# Return empty string on value not found postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, rust

I am running a postgres server and I am trying to fetch a certain value as shown below. There is a chance that the query may find nothing. How can I accommodate this best and just return and empty string instead? This is written in rust by the way

```
    let mut curr_amount: i32;
    for row in client.query("SELECT * FROM drugs WHERE id=$1", &[&id])? {
        let s: String = row.get(1);
        curr_amount = s.parse().unwrap();
```

I tried what I showed above

Comment: If all that you're interested in is the first ordinal value (`row.get(1)`), then you can use `COALESCE`. For example, `SELECT COALESCE(column, 'default_value') FROM drugs ...`.

Comment: @filpa: When no record has been found, there is no record with default_value either. Your comment doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @FrankHeikens You're right, it seems I misread the question. In that case, I suppose OP could check `row.is_empty()` ([docs](https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/row/struct.Row.html#method.is_empty)) first and add a branch based on that.

Comment: Thank You! row.is_empty() Worked perfectly

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can try using the `query_one` method

```
use postgres::{Client, NoTls};

    let mut client = Client::connect("postgresql://user:password@localhost/mydatabase", NoTls)?;
    
    let result = client.query_one("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable", &[])?;
    let count: i64 = result.get(0);
    
    println!("result: {}", count);
```

Comment: Why would you execute an extra query? Makes your code slow by design. Just use is_empty() to see if any results have been found. https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/row/struct.Row.html#method.is_empty